# SObject deployment: Cannot specify a startsWith attribute for this language

Tags: deployment, sobject, language

I'm trying to deploy an sobject to a new empty environment. I get the following error:

```
Cannot specify a startsWith attribute for this language
```

Both orgs are in English. Any thoughts?

**Edit**: The metadata of the sobject contains the line:

```
<startsWith>vowel</startsWith>
```

Comment: could you add the metadata of the sObject?

Comment: Have you checked that a) both orgs share the same company language b) both users share the same language and c) both orgs share the same active languages at the translation workbench?

Comment: a) yes, English b) yes, English c) Translation Workbench languages are deployed in the same deployment. Probably the language was different when the sobject was first created..